# Can't Get Batch Processes To Complete/Start Anymore - No Progress Bar

Tags: batch-operations

I have tried many different actions that use the /batch?op=start&id operation in Drupal. For some reason, nothing is working anymore. Can't download module updates, delete users, run VBO operations or anything of the sort.

I have searched what seems like everywhere and some people have experienced this, but haven't posted their solutions.

Can someone please help me solve this. All of these functions are required on this site regularly and now it's not working.

Thank you!

Billy

Comment: I had problems with this in the past where one operation was causing timeouts and stopping other batch operations. Clearing the batch table did the trick for me. (make a backup just in case!)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Neograph734 - I'm kicking myself. Turns out that Jquery wasn't reloading in SSL due to being aggregated under admin/performance. Thanks!

Comment: It should be safe to aggregate javascript, but make sure to clear the cache afterwards ;)