# Why doesn't batch API run for user deletion?

Tags: 7, users, batch-operations

On a client's website, batch operations don't run when cancelling/deleting a user account (No progress bar shows up and no process runs). Neither of the users have any content related to them as they're accidental duplicates. There are [no related error messages](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/123873/deleting-user-accounts-produces-error) in the logs or on the batch page. There isn't any issue when deleting users on the local copy. (This leads me to rule out corrupt include files.) **Why does this happen on the live site and not locally?**

The problem started after a core update, so another update might not solve the problem.

What I've tried:

1. Check file permissions on `/includes/batch*.inc` (r-xr-xr--)
2. Backup and truncate the `batch` table, followed by a cache flush
3. Disable JS aggregation, as suggested in "[Can't Get Batch Process to Start/Complete Any More](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/137882/17584)". However, this removes the administration menu.
4. Use the `/devel/php` page to run `user_delete()` for the users in question. However, I don't want to advise my client to run this.

Comment: Do you use, on live site, external backend for cache?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by 'external backend'. Do you mean something like XCache, APC, etc? If so, I don't know.

Comment: do you have varnish, memcache, memcache_storage, apc o redis modules installed?

Comment: No, as far as I can tell from looking at the site's output for `phpinfo()`. lOcally, I'm using XCache.

Comment: I mean drupal modules ;)

Comment: No, nothing (not even boost). It looks like caching is done however Drupal does it by default.